# Numpy dtype view

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm following the tutorial shown in the lonk below, section Dtype views:

https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html

I've reproduced it below:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.arange(10, dtype='int16')
b
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int16)
v3 = b.view('int32')
v3 += 1
b
#array([1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9], dtype=int16)
v4 = b.view('int8')
v4
#array([1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 9, 0], dtype=int8)
```

I am primarily confused as to why v3 which comes out as?

```
array([ 65536, 196610, 327684, 458758, 589832], dtype=int32)
```

Despite appearances v3 is still equal to b when viewed as ('int16') as the following code confirms:

```
v3.view('int16')
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int16)
```

I'm also a bit confused by the value of b after the addition expression v3 += 1:

```
array([1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9], dtype=int16)
```

Here (1, dtype='int32') is being added to v3, which in turn adds it to b.

Will such view, dtype expressions always update the array that is being viewed, in this case b?

As the ('int32') dtype is twice as big, it will have double the length of the 'int16' values and so it overwrites two of them at a time, it's stride will also be twice as big and so it picks up every second number in b.

Is this interpretation correct?

Why is each figure returned twice, rather than just returning a truncated b?

```
array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], dtype=int16)
```

Comment: In int16 terms the +=1 appears to add [1,0,1,0,...] to b, giving appearance of doubling.

Answer (score 3):

This is related with how array is stored. In **contiguous** (important!) order, the actual memory block of `b` looks like

```
[0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0...]
```

where each number represents a `byte` in the memory. A block of memory can be viewed as any `dtype`. When viewed as `int16`, two `byte`s form a number, and the result becomes

```
[00 10 20 30 40 50 60 70...]
```

when viewed as `int32`, four `byte`s form a number, and the result becomes

```
[0010 2030 4050...]
```

modern PCs use **little-endian** to store number. This means e.g. `int32(1234)` should be interpreted as `1*256^0 + 2*256^1 + 3*256^2 + 4*256^3` while `int16(56)` should be interpreted as `5*256^0 + 6*256^1`. For this reason, `0010` becomes `65536`, `2030` becomes `196610`, etc.

When adding one to `int32` view, since `int32` view is technically sharing the same memory block with `int16` array (view is always sharing memory block with view-ed array), the `int16` array will also be modified. Adding `int32` one means adding `1000` (i.e. add one to the most left number in `xxxx`), which corresponds to the `256^0` term in every **even** position number:

```
int32 view: [1010 3030 5050 7070]
int16 view: [10 10 30 30 50 50 70 70]
```

Therefore, int16 view translates to `[1 1 3 3 5 5 7 7...]`.

BTW:

- The literal `1` do not have a `dtype`. It might be typed `long` (i.e. `int32`) when numpy cannot decide a better type. But when doing something like `a += 1`, the number will be typed the `dtype` of `a`
- Numpy supports **big-endian** array (i.e. the `int32(1234)` above becomes `4321` in memory). In this case the result of modifying view would be totally different
- Numpy also supports array that's actually stored in the reverse direction (i.e. `[int16(10), int16(20), int16(30), int16(40)]` is actually `[4 0 3 0 2 0 1 0]` in memory).  This will also have an effect
- Integer have a sign bit at the first bit of the last byte. Which means if the integer is negative, the result would be way beyond your expectation.

Your ideas that "viewing" as different `dtype` should not change the value in a random manner refers to `cast`ing (i.e. `astype`). Casting returns a new copy with the same value but different `dtype`. Due to size difference of `dtype`, casting cannot share memory with the original array, and it's more or less in-efficient.